# On my minecraft sever i cant get my hunger bar to go down HELP

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have tried everything I have looked every where pease help

Answer (score 1):

You must be on either Peaceful on Creative Mode. If you change this to Easy Mode or above, the hunger bar shall go down.